# Fragment Added in View Pager Load Wrong Data

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have Total 7 fragments in view pager, I am using same fragment in the all the pager item as `ProductListingFragment`. And Fill Data on `public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser)` getting called. Now first fragment works fine but when I move to second fragment it is not fill the data in adapter and it show the data of second fragment in third fragment.

Here is my code to add Child fragment in Viewpager :

```
viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.tiresViewpager);

    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0);



    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            pagePosition = position;
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(pagePosition);

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tabs);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void getVolleyRequestResponse(VolleyRequestResponse volleyResponse) {

    switch (volleyResponse.type) {

        case 0:
            try {

                JSONObject objJson = new JSONObject(volleyResponse.output);

                if (objJson.optInt(Param.KEY_STATUS_CODE) == Param.SUCCESS_CODE) {

                    adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());

                    JSONArray jsonArray = objJson.getJSONArray("data");

                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                        JSONObject categoryObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        adapter.addFragment(new ProductListingFragment(), categoryObject.getString("name"));
                        categoryId.add(categoryObject.getString("id"));
                    }
                    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
                    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
    }
}

class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();


    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {

        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

Hear is the code to load data in fragment

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_productlisting, container, false);

    setHasOptionsMenu(true);


    rv_Products = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rv_product);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {

    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);

    if (isVisibleToUser) {

        handler = new Handler();
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        getProductList();
    }
}


public static void setGrid(Activity activity) {
    isList = false;
    GridLayoutManager lm = new GridLayoutManager(activity, 2);
    rv_Products.setLayoutManager(lm);
    adapter = new ProductFeatureAdapter(list, rv_Products, "grid");
    rv_Products.setAdapter(adapter);
}

public void getProductList() {

    new VolleyRequest(getActivity(), VolleyRequest.Method.POST, Url.getProductList, Param.productList(TiresFragment.categoryId.get(TiresFragment.pagePosition), page_count + ""), 0, true, this);
}

@Override
public void getVolleyRequestResponse(VolleyRequestResponse volleyResponse) {

    switch (volleyResponse.type) {

        case 0:
            try {

                JSONObject objJson = new JSONObject(volleyResponse.output);

                if (objJson.optInt(Param.KEY_STATUS_CODE) == Param.SUCCESS_CODE) {

                    JSONArray featureProductArray = objJson.getJSONArray("response");
                    total_page = objJson.getInt("totalPages");

                    if (!isLoading) {

                        for (int i = 0; i < featureProductArray.length(); i++) {

                            JSONObject object = featureProductArray.getJSONObject(i);

                            list.add(new Product(object.getString("id"),
                                    object.getString("productname"),
                                    "",
                                    object.getString("imageurl"),
                                    object.getString("price"),
                                    "",
                                    false,
                                    false,
                                    false,
                                    0,
                                    0));
                        }

                    } else {

                        ArrayList<Product> tmp_list = new ArrayList<>();

                        for (int i = 0; i < featureProductArray.length(); i++) {

                            JSONObject object = featureProductArray.getJSONObject(i);

                            tmp_list.add(new Product(object.getString("id"),
                                    object.getString("name"),
                                    object.getString("category"),
                                    object.getString("imageurl"),
                                    object.getString("price"),
                                    object.getString("type"),
                                    false,
                                    false,
                                    false,
                                    0,
                                    0));
                        }

                        list.addAll(tmp_list);
                    }

                    set_recycler();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
    }
}

private void set_recycler() {

        Log.e("AAKASH", "IF LOAD " + isLoading + "");
        Log.e("AAKASH", "IF PAGE COUNT " + page_count + "");
        Log.e("AAKASH", "IF TOTAL PAGE " + total_page + "");
        isList = false;
        GridLayoutManager lm = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2);
        rv_Products.setLayoutManager(lm);
        Log.i("niral", "FRAGMENT CALLLED  SET ADAPTER " + TiresFragment.pagePosition);

        adapter = new ProductFeatureAdapter(list, rv_Products, "grid");
        rv_Products.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/15261142/4049612](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15261142/4049612) check this will solve your problem

Comment: I am also facing this problem....

Comment: i am also getting fragment added issue in view pager